# Error try to uploading app to the app store,

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile

I'm new to from xamarin and I'm trying to publish my app xamarin ios, So when I [try to uploading it to the app store,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hDIX.png)
I got the following error.

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is obvious. It said *Authentication Failed*.

You should sign in with an app-specific password. Create the password at https://appleid.apple.com.

Comment: Thank you for everything, I can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio to upload to the app store works great, if there are no errors. I tend to use [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) to check my package and upload instead. You can upload your artifact directly, or from Visual Studio, publish your artifact and save it instead of pushing it to the store. Then use Transporter to check your artifact. The error message will be much more readable ... if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

@Raptor's answer above worked for me with the following specifics:

I had to change my Apple account password.  After changing my Apple account password, my app-specific password was gone from my Apple account. I needed to create a new app-specific password.  The complete list of steps I needed to restore my ability to publish apps with Visual Studio (after changing my Apple account password) is as follows:

1. Open XCode > Preferences and re-sign into my account (XCode showed that my account login had expired).  I signed in with my new password.
2. Open Visual Studio > Preferences > Apple Developer Accounts and remove and re-add the account (login with new password)
3. Visit https://appleid.apple.com and within the Security block, click the "Edit" button to confirm that your app-specific password is gone. Then click "Generate Password" and use the new app-specific password when publishing apps.